# jQuery.each loop adding empty values to array

Tags: arrays, json, jquery

I have a jQuery.each loop iterating through a JSON object that has three sets of data, but for some reason the loop outputs 13 objects instead of 3, and 10 of them are empty. Here is my code:

```
var teammates_info=[];
var teammate_json={"teammates":[{"id":"12","first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Johnson","user_img":"","status":"offline","new_messages":"0"},{"id":"9","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","user_img":"","status":"offline","new_messages":"0"},{"id":"10","first_name":"test","last_name":"test","user_img":"","status":"offline","new_messages":"0"}]};

jQuery.each(teammate_json.teammates,function(index,teammate){
    teammates_info[teammate.id]=[{"first_name":teammate.first_name,"last_name":teammate.last_name,"user_img":teammate.user_img,"status":teammate.status,"new_messages":teammate.new_messages}];
}); 

console.log(teammates_info.length); //outputs 13 not 3
```

If I do a `document.write(teammates_info);` I get `,,,,,,,,,[object Object],[object Object],,[object Object]`, so you can see all the empty array elements that are being created.

I am trying to output an array of objects, that way I can reference a teammate's data later in my code like `teammates_info[12]["first_name"]`, but I am stumped as to why 13 array elements are created instead of just 3.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7bZtV/3/   Use push(), don't set your specific indexes for array. Otherwise, use an non indexed object, not an array

Comment: @A.Wolff I need to set a specific index that way I can reference it by the teammate's ID later in the code.

Comment: Just edited my previous comment, so use an object, not an array

Comment: Ok. I will give that a try.

Comment: see: http://jsfiddle.net/7bZtV/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use non indexed object, not an array:

```
var teammates_info = {};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7bZtV/5/)